# How can I determine (and then amend) BizTalk Server Operator permissions for viewing WCF-BasicHttp bindings?

Tags: security, permissions, biztalk, biztalk-2010

How can I determine (and then amend) BizTalk Server Operator permissions for viewing WCF-BasicHttp bindings?

The issue is some users are in the BizTalk Server Operators group, and when they look at the binding of a WCF-BasicHttp send port, they see what I presume are the default values ... open 1min, send 1min, etc.

But if a member of the BizTalk Server Adminstrators checks the  binding, the actual values are seen ... open 2min, etc.

I'm presuming the operator group permissions through the BizTalk.ExplorerOM and/or stored proc's isn't correct for reading the values ... making a change and get the expected "Permission denied ..."

So how to track down where the data is, or in this case, isn't coming from?

And then how to update it to provide read-only?

**EDIT:**
*And just to check, had him export the bindings and compared with my export, and the XML is the same ... **except** that the  element is missing from the export by the Operator for all transport types, i.e. SMTP, FILE, WCF-SQL, etc. not just WCF-BasicHttp*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the scope of what any of the built in Groups can do.

Admittedly, I have never used the BizTalk Server Operators Group so I'm not really sure exactly what you should get when Viewing or exporting Ports, but it's documented that BizTalk Server Operators cannot modify any configuration so maybe this is just an odd side effect of that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578061.aspx

Since BizTalk Server Operators can't modify, it is effectively read-only, just wrong as well :)

If that user is somehow overwriting with the default configuration, then you have found a bug.

Comment: Did some poking around and there are posts like, e.g. http://kundankarma.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/biztalk-server-admin-console-on-read.html and http://blog.cnext.eu/2009/06/16/biztalk-security-%e2%80%93-adding-permissions-to-the-biztalk-operator-role/ where they've "tweaked" the Operator permissions ... bet it's not supported by Microsoft though!

Comment: Not supported at all.  If you want to provide customized user experiences, BizTalk 360 is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, seen demos of BizTalk 360 ... well impressed